# Stop r-value invoking move assignment C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider a simple C++ class that I do not want to modify:

```
class foo {};
```

Then if I do the following I will invoke the move assignment operator:

```
foo f{};

f = foo{};
```

Is there a way to invoke copy assignment without modifying `foo` or using an intermediate `g` like this:

```
foo f{};
foo g{};
f = g;
```

Almost as if there were `std::dont_move`!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the *actual* problem you have? *Why* don't you want move-semantics in this case?

Comment: Just wondered if the opposite of std::move is possible without using, say, an explicit reference.

Comment: Why would you want that? It almost sounds like you have a bug you're trying to hide.

Comment: Do you want to `delete` the move assignment, or just sometimes make sure it copies instead?

Comment: @doctorlove, sometimes make sure it copies instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::dont_move()` is easy to implement by yourself:

```
template <typename T>
const T& force_copy(T&& v)
{
    return v;
}
```

See [usage example](http://cpp.sh/46scn)

Answer (score 4):

You can write:

```
f = static_cast<foo const&>(foo{});
```